# Choosing hash functions used by Guava Bloom filters

Tags: java, hash, guava, bloom-filter

When creating a Bloom filter with the Guava library you are expected to give a funnel and a expected number of insertions (and optionally a wanted false positive rate). Is there a way to set which hash functions the Bloom filter is supposed to use? If there is no way to set the hash function what is used by default?

Bloom filter are a part of com.google.common.hash which provides a variety of different hash functions. Unfortunately https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/HashingExplained could not answer my question but shows the available hash functions and gives some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default hash function is a [128-bit murmur3 hash function (x64 variant)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.1-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/hash/Hashing.html#murmur3_128--) (see [BloomFilterStrategies enum](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilterStrategies.java)).

You can't specify the hash function using the public API. However, using a little hack you could do it - you'd need to:

1. Place a custom class in `com.google.common.hash` package to call [BloomFilter](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/hash/BloomFilter.java).`create(
     Funnel<? super T> funnel, long expectedInsertions, double fpp, Strategy strategy)`
2. Create a custom implementation of `BloomFilter.Strategy` (the easiest way would be to copy one of the implementations from `BloomFilterStrategies`, and turn the hash function into a field).

However, make sure that you really need a custom function. [Murmur3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) is really fast (though not secure), and every other hash function will most likely be much slower, so perhaps the only benefit you might hope for are fewer collisions.